# Preg match from text with number

Tags: php, preg-match

Need get result after R[number]

for example

```
$text = "Bridgestone Turanza T001 XL R16 205/55 94W TL";
```

need get

**R16 205/55 94W TL**

Comment: That matches `R` followed by anything, not just numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started:

```
$text = "Bridgestone Turanza T001 XL R16 205/55 94W TL";
preg_match("/\bR\d+ (.*)$/",$text, $matches);
print_r( $matches );
```

Matches R at beginning of word, followed by one or more numbers, then a space and captures everything thereafter in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are looking for is:
    /R[0-9].*/

Comment: That works OK but given the one example, it's better to have the space in front and behind, to match more specifically.